# How to create a new variable which is the union of two other variables using dplyr?

Tags: r, union, dplyr

I have this data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), b = c(1:6), c = c(1,2,3,5,7,8))

a b c
-----
1 1 1
1 2 2
2 3 3
2 4 5
3 5 7
3 6 8
```

I want for each value in variable a, to keep *only* a new variable d, the unique union of variables b and c:

```
a d
---
1 1
1 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
```

Something like this will of course return an error:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(a) %>%
mutate(d = union(b, c))
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution? Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be using "dplyr"?

Comment: No, I just really like dplyr. It has to be without looping though. Thanks.

Comment: (+1) for a reproducible example and showing what you've tried. Nice for a first question on SO.

Comment: Ananda's solution is great. Just another way: `setDT(df)[, .(d = union(b,c)), by=a)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest "data.table" for this:

```
library(data.table)
unique(as.data.table(df)[, list(d = unlist(.SD)), by = a])
#    a d
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 1 2
# 3: 2 3
# 4: 2 4
# 5: 2 5
# 6: 3 5
# 7: 3 6
# 8: 3 7
# 9: 3 8
```

---

I suppose a similar approach in "dplyr" would be to also use "tidyr", like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(var, d, b:c) %>% 
  select(-var) %>% 
  unique
#    a d
# 1  1 1
# 2  1 2
# 3  2 3
# 4  2 4
# 5  3 5
# 6  3 6
# 10 2 5
# 11 3 7
# 12 3 8
```